# How do get clean URLs like Stack Overflow?

Tags: .net, architecture, url-routing, httphandler

On some .NET driven sites URLs don't end with asp.net page names, like default.aspx, instead they use a pattern http://sitename.com or http://sitename.com/subdirectory/subdirectory. The site is mapped as sub directories off the root, ie. /tags, /users, /badges, the URLs would be /tags, /users, /badges respectively.

Stack Overflow, to use a specific example, uses question URLs of the form [How do get clean URLs like Stackoverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035251/how-do-get-clean-urls-like-stackoverflow). Which is great way to optimize the page for search engines.

Is this implemented using HTTP handlers? Is the GET request filtered based on path and the whole response is formed in the handler itself based on the question id? Anyone else care to speculate?

Comment: This question has been asked so many times before.

Comment: I beleive stack overflow is built using the ASP.NET MVC framework, see www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Drop the SO references and this is a great question.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131/is-stackoverflowcom-written-in-ruby-on-rails, with a different speculation.

Comment: Wow; a legitimate question gets down-voted three times, marked falsely as "duplicate" to a question about ROR, called "not a real question" even though it is - and my reference to url_rewriting is down-voted. This is a complete fiasco! :)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Comment: Essentially the guy wants to know how the routing works, and is using stackoverflow as a frame of reference.  Give him a break.

Comment: How is this a dupe? Do any of those links actually answer his question?

Comment: @Doug R++; I agree. There is a sense of esotericism here that gets a bit annoying. SOFlow has may professionals, and we all need to be mindful that we share this platform with those new to the field.

Comment: @Nosredna - they don't have to answer the question to be a dupe. They only have to ask the same (or close-enough) question to be considered a dupe. We certainly don't want the question being asked in multiple places, and thus assuring us that dupes will be created.

Comment: StackOverflow is a web application.

Comment: Right, but how does he get his answer if no one has given it in the other questions? I think people read his question as "what is SO made with" when he was not quite asking that.

Comment: I think he should read the blog post etc., more carefully, then come back with individual questions that do not ask about SO.

Comment: I think the pedants should go be pedantic elsewhere. There's nothing wrong with using SO as a reference to the question.

Comment: @Nosredna, sending him to a thread that doesn't have the answer is acceptable, since that thread is already *working* on an answer presumably. If it's not, those who participated are still waiting. Anybody who answers here is abandoning those who have been waiting there - if we can focus all of the traffic there, we're better off. @mmyers - I agree, I don't see any reason to close this question (aside from it being dupe-ish). It's a legitimate question, regardless if it's about SO's structure or not.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: I don't agree. Often, having multiple "similar" questions can be beneficial as everyone asks things differently and therefore having lots of slightly different questions increases the chances of finding answers. However, they do need to be linked for that to work well, but consolidating into one question defeats that benefit of multiple question styles.

Comment: @Jeff, I agree that allowing many people to ask a question helps. And perhaps funneling them all into one room (metaphorically) isn't the best solution, but I don't think keeping them all apart and potentially only giving the answer some is good either. I prefer funneling them to be honest, even though I see the inherent problems with that.

Comment: @Jeff: the question should be edited to be about sites _like_ SO, not about SO itself. It should be "how do I accomplish this", not about "how did SO accomplish this". I say that considering there are some great answers here, and I don't want to see this question closed.

Comment: @Jon & John: I see your points and I somewhat agree and somewhat don't. :) Such is the nature of the Internet.

Comment: @shankar: how would you feel if your question were reopened and edited to be less about SO itself, and more about the techniques you see exhibited by sites like SO? There are many good answers here, and I think this question should be the place to which we direct the inevitable duplicates.

Comment: @John Saunders: No problem, feel free to edit the question.
@everyone else: Thanks to all the great people who answered the question. ASP.NET routing (given first by Doug R) is what I was looking for, other answers about url rewriting is great too. I'll be using a combination of these two techniques. Thanks again.

Comment: Those possible duplicates have NOTHING to do with the question he is asking. I'm going to take a stab at editing this.

Comment: made question more generic. also "possible duplicates" were not - one was about UI, other was technology stack.

Comment: @Shankar, I've attempted to edit your question into a more generic one. Hopefully I've been faithful to your original question. Please edit it if I have not.

Comment: @Rex M, sorry didn't mean to step on your edits, I think we both had the same idea at the same time.

Comment: Now we have a problem, because those of us who offered more general answers to the original more general question are in danger of getting down-voted for now having answers that are too vague, or way off topic - uh'oh.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's ASP.Net MVC, which has the .Net Routing more or less built in.  The Routing is available for non MVC projects as well, though

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

It's just a .dll you can drop in your bin folder.  Basically it uses regular expressions to match your URL's to pages/templates.

Comment: As of ASP.NET 4.0, better URL Routing integration for Web Forms is available, announced in late 2009: [URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series) - ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Answer (score 18):

This is achieved with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in Apache, or similar methods of [url_rewriting on IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Note: SOFlow uses the latter.

Comment: Probably because it's well documented that the site doesn't use Apache.

Comment: Did I say it uses Apache? No. The asker was interested in how the URL's work. He didn't specify that he was interested in how they work from a .NET perspective. I offered an answer for both Apache and IIS.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson the title does indicate/imply that he is asking about how SO does it but it isn't explicitly stated in the question itself. +1 for your answer still being correct regardless.

Comment: @Bryan, I agree that he's using SO as the example, but we shouldn't assume that he must therefore be expecting only the technologies that SO uses (since he obviously don't know what they are to begin with). I am a PHP developer, and yet I might ask "how did SO accomplish x..." so that I can emulate it within my own sphere of technologies. I just want to make sure I'm not assuming too much when it comes to answering a question :) Thanks for the ++;

Answer (score 5):

The URLs are in that format following [REST principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) in which everything is a resource with an unique URL.

I think I read somewhere in the blog that this is achieved by using [ASP.NET MVC framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/).

Answer (score 3):

I know that Stack Overflow is using the ASP.NET MVC framework, which presumably has a URL rewriting system built-in.  For non-Windows system, Apache mod_rewrite is very common.

For example, a wiki page: `http://server.com/wiki/Main_Page` request is handled by the webserver.  It's translated into `/wiki/index.php?page=Main_Page`

Here's an example of URL rewriting in Apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

What this says is if the URL that comes in is `forum-##.html` then process that request as if it were `forumdisplay.php?fid=##`.  The same goes for the `thread-##.html` rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in ASP.net by using [`Context.RewritePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wkk6d(v=vs.110).aspx).

In **Global.asax**, create an [**Application.BeginRequest**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler.

For example, if you want to make requests of

```
example.com/questions
```

actually return the results from

```
example.com/Questions/Default.aspx
```

**Global.asax**:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">

   void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string originalPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToLower();

       if (originalPath.Contains("/questions"))
       {
           String newPath = originalPath.Replace("/questions", "/Questions/Questions.aspx");
           Context.RewritePath(newPath);
       }
    }
</script>
```

If your web-site is running anything before .NET Framework 4, you will have to manually turn on the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` in **web.config**, otherwise the **BeginRequest** event will not get fired:

```
<configuration>
...
   <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```